# How to use freeze_graph.py tool in TensorFlow v1

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to use the [`freeze_graph.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.0/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) tool with models saved via `saver.save` in TensorFlow v1? If so, how?

I have code that looks roughly like this:

```py
supervisor = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=output_directory_path)

with supervisor.managed_session() as session:
    # train the model here
    supervisor.saver.save(session, output_directory_path)
```

This produces a directory containing:

```py
checkpoint
output
output-16640.data-00000-of-00001
output-16640.index
output-16640.meta
```

Where `output` is a directory containing the files for intermediate training steps. The rest are files.

My understanding is that this is a meta graph (the `.meta` file) and its variables (the `.data*` file) in saver v2 format. These files contain the data needed for the `freeze_graph.py` tool but it is unclear how to tell the `freeze_graph.py` tool to load the data from these files.

All of these attempts produce the error message `Input checkpoint '...' doesn't exist!`

```py
python freeze_graph.py --input_checkpoint checkpoint --output_graph /tmp/out
python freeze_graph.py --input_checkpoint . --output_graph /tmp/out
python freeze_graph.py --input_checkpoint output-16640 --output_graph /tmp/out
```

The `freeze_graph.py` code includes the comment `'input_checkpoint' may be a prefix if we're using Saver V2 format` next to where the `--input_checkpoint` argument is used so I had thought the third of the above attempts would work but, alas, no.

Comment: As a hunch, can you try prepending `./` to the checkpoint name and calling `python freeze_graph.py --input_checkpoint ./output-16640 --output_graph /tmp/out` and see if that works?

Comment: @mrry That did it, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @mrry pointed out in a comment, the answer to this particular question is to prefix the output prefix with `./`. When this was done I discovered it is also necessary to provide values for the `--input_graph` and `--output_name_names` arguments.

The command now looks like

```
python freeze_graph.py \
    --input_graph output/graph.pbtxt \
    --input_checkpoint ./output-16640 \
    --output_graph /tmp/out \
    --output_node_names <name>
```

Unfortunately my graph contains variables for pre-loaded data which causes `freeze_graph.py` to fail with a message like `Attempting to use uninitialized value ...`; solving this subsequent problem is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: what if the output of summarize is this? `Found 1 possible inputs: (name=image_tensor, type=uint8(4), shape=[?,?,?,3]) 
No variables spotted.
Found 4 possible outputs: (name=detection_boxes, op=Identity) (name=detection_scores, op=Identity) (name=detection_classes, op=Identity) (name=num_detections, op=Identity) `

Comment: for the `input_checkpoint`, no file extension such as ".ckpt"?

Comment: What about the `input_binary` flag?

Comment: what should we put in the "output_node" argument?