# TensorFlow: freeze graph tensorflow for poets

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow and I'm following the tensorflow for poets 2 tutorial and clone their repo: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2

In the tutorial I learned how to run the scripts for retraining, evaluation, optimize for inference, quantize_graph in cmd. **Now I'm curious about "Freezing".**

In this stackoverflow question I learned on how to run the freeze_graph in cmd:
[How to use freeze_graph.py tool in TensorFlow v1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439233/how-to-use-freeze-graph-py-tool-in-tensorflow-v1)

The problem is this so called "checkpoint" which I didn't have when following the tutorial tensorflow for poets 2. **My question is how do I obtain this checkpoint file? Since I only have the .pb and labels after training my data**

Note: I'm aware that there is no freeze_graph.py in the repo above thats why I copied it from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/tools in hope that I can use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain a checkpoint file, I used the script train_image_classifier.py from the slim library : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#Training.

It worked well on the different tests I made, also with new datasets. You can either train from scratch or fine-tune an existing model.

Regards,
Stephane

Comment: thanks for the link, there's even existing checkpoint files for different models

Answer (score 0):

A .pb file is a frozen graph of checkpoint file. What you need is re-train your model and save it into a TF checkpoint file format. Use `tf.train.Saver` to do it. See [this instruction](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model) for its usage. Then you can use `freeze_graph.py` to do whatever you want next.